# Does a simple monolith application need kubernetes to manage

Tags: docker, kubernetes, infrastructure

I'm very new to the infrastructure so I built a simple monolith application and I use docker for building a container and deploy it on my linux server. My question is, do I need to install kubernetes for a single container and if no how can I scale or do the load balancing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"*... do I need to install kubernetes for a single container*" - No, it is not mandatory. One can use docker to manage applications. Kubernetes is a platform that *can* be used to orchestrate containerized applications. It offers tools and concepts like [autoscaling](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/) based on load, isolation through [namespaces](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/), network access management through [services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) and [ingresses](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/), and much more. But Kubernetes is not the only platform for orchestration. There are others, for example [OpenShift](https://www.openshift.com/), [docker swarm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/), [rancher](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v1.2/en/). All those are optional platforms with additional tooling and concepts that can be used if necessary.

"*how can I scale or do the load balancing.*" - We can, for example, define the replicas [through the `replicas` variable in a `docker-compose` file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#replicas). All containers defined under a service are accessed through this service's name. How exactly the balancing is done can also be configured through the [`endpoint_mode` configuration](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#endpoint_mode). If we need even more control, we can deploy a separate load balancer, e.g. nginx. A possible configuration is described in [this medium article](https://medium.com/@benoittellier3/automatic-load-balancing-for-your-docker-compose-services-aa6b96f20d20).

---

For future posts, [please limit yourself to one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post).